# I can't upload a image from Android in expo

Tags: react-native, axios

It's expo(react native) project and I try to upload an image as form data to server
In iOS It's working well but in Anrdoi it doesn't work

====request======

```
const form = new FormData()
const fileName = payload.img.split('/')[payload.img.split('/').length - 1]
form.append('fImage', {
   uri: payload.img,
   type: `image/${fileName.split('.')[fileName.split('.').length - 1]}`,
   name: fileName
})
axios({
  url:API_URL + url,
  method:'patch',
  data:formDat,
  headers:{  
  'Authorization': token,
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data, application/json'
  }
 })
```

=======response======

```
  [AxiosError: Network Error]
```

======version=======

```
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
```

Always in iOS, Working out but android..
My API_URL is not localhost I put ip address

Answer (score 0):

It might be that debugging cause the issue, did uploading work when debugging is disabled?

Maybe your issue is related to:

1. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/38
2. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4910
3. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/639c02c0f3385c83e62b0ca483cb989db0e4b1a4/docs/network-inspect-of-chrome-devtools.md

Comment: I solved this, I just request without header